# Processing rather big text files on serverless AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to figure out an architecture for processing rather big files (maybe few hundred MB) on a serverless AWS. This is what I've got so far:

```
API Gateway -> S3 -> Lambda function -> SNS -> Lambda function
```

In this scenario, the text file is uploaded to S3 through API Gateway. Then some Lambda function is called based on the event generated on S3. This Lambda function will open the text file and read it line by line, generating tasks to be done as messages in an SNS topic. Each message will invoke a separate Lambda function process the task.

My only concern is the first Lambda function call. What if it times out? How can I make sure that it's not a point of failure?

Comment: What is the file's format? JSON? CSV?

Comment: You can say CSV, but it's more like customized format. It's safe to say you can read them line by line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ask S3 to only return a particular byte range of a given object, using the `Range` header: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html

for example:

```
Range: bytes=0-9
```

would return only the first 10 bytes of the S3 object.

To read a file line by line, you would have to decide on a specific chunk size (1 MB for example), read 1 chunk of the file at a time and split the chunk by line (by looking for newline characters). Once the whole chunk has been read, you could re-invoke the lambda and pass the chunk pointer as a parameter. The new invocation of the lambda will read the file from the chunk pointer given as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

First thing to know is that the Lambda CPU available is proportional to its configured RAM size. So, double the RAM gets you double the CPU.

If scaling up the Lambda doesn't do it ... then some back of a napkin ideas:

1. One workflow might be: if size of CSV less than X (to be determined)
   then process in a single Lambda. If size more than X then invoke N
   sub-lambdas, pointing them each at a 1/Nth of the input file
   (assuming you can split the workload like this). The Lambdas use the get range feature of S3. This is a kind of map/reduce pattern.
2. Or maybe use Step Functions. Have a 1st Lambda invocation begin to
   process the file, keeping track of the time remaining (available
   from the context object), and respond to Step Functions to indicate
   how far it got. Then Step Functions invokes a subsequent Lambda to
   process the next part of the file and so on, until complete.
3. Or use EC2, containers, or even EMR (obviously not serverless).

Also, note that Lambda functions have [limited diskspace](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html#limits-list) (500MB) so if you need to download the file to disk in order to process it, then it will need to be under 500MB, notwithstanding any other diskspace you might need to use. Optionally, you can work around this diskspace limitation by simply reading the file into memory (and resize the Lambda function up to 3GB as needed).

Comment: If the file is larger than 500mb, you could also give the lambda a lot of RAM and store the file in memory

Comment: @cementblocks You're right, that's an important clarification to make so I'll update my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use AWS Batch instead of lambda for the heavy stuff.

1. create docker container with your code, load it to ECS, than create job-definition to run it.
2. use lambda to submit this job with input file as parameter.
3. op1: create dependent job this the 2nd stage processing, which will lunch automatically when first job succeded.
   op2: use step function to orchestrate all the scenario (note that the integration between step function and Batch is not ideal..)